# How to determine which part of adapter was called in Android

Tags: android, listview

I have an adapter for a `ListView` that where each item contains a `CheckBox` and a `Textview`. When the checkbox is clicked on, I would simply like it to check or uncheck as normal. However, when the `TextView` is clicked on, I would like to start a new sub-activity.

Currently, I am handling onClick behavior using `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` and I can determine which row of the `ListView` was clicked using the `position` parameter. What is the best way to determine whether the click came from the `CheckBox` or `TextView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside getView() of ur adapter

```
tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View viewIn)
              {
              }
            }
        });
```

Comment: How would I determine whether or not the click came from the checkbox or the TextView?

Comment: It is on tv , it will never fire for checkbox.

Comment: I think I might try something else but this is the correct answer to the question I asked.